# how to use switch case in macro for entire data set in excel

Tags: excel, vba, case

I need help to execute macro switch case for entire data set in Excel.
columnA contains cities names and in column B I want its respective states when macro is executed.
The following code provides me with the state for the first cell i.e. when A2=mumbai,the macro will give me output in B2=maharashtra.
I want to run this macro for my entire data set in column A and get respective states in column B.
Please help.

```
Sub Macro()

Dim Score As String
Dim Result As String
'Dim i As Long

Score = Range("A1").Value
Select Case Score
    Case Is = "mumbai", "nagpur", "ahmedabad"
        Result = "maharashtra"
    Case Is = "surat", "vadodara", "jamnagar"
        Result = "gujarat"
    Case Is = "indore", "bhopal", "jabalpur"
        Result = "madhya pradesh"
    Case Else
        Result = "BLANK"
End Select

Range("B1").Value = Result

End Sub
```

Comment: have you tested the code below ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through column A

```
Sub Macro()

Dim Score As String
Dim Result As String
Dim last_row As Long


last_row = Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'Dim i As Long

For Row = 1 To last_row
    Score = Range("A" & Row).Value
    Select Case Score
        Case Is = "mumbai", "nagpur", "ahmedabad"
            Result = "maharashtra"
        Case Is = "surat", "vadodara", "jamnagar"
            Result = "gujarat"
        Case Is = "indore", "bhopal", "jabalpur"
            Result = "madhya pradesh"
        Case Else
            Result = "BLANK"
    End Select

    Range("B" & Row).Value = Result
Next Row

End Sub
```